# A "bump" in the cooling curve of naphthalene?

Tags: thermal-radiation, chemical-compounds, cooling, cryogenics

While doing an experiment, I noticed a slight bump in the cooling curve. I have searched for it on the internet and all of the articles say that it is something related to super-cooling.

The graph's bump is shown below:
[image]

X Axis is time, Y Axis is the temperature.

What is the specific reason for this?

Comment: Since there is absolutely no detail in the graph, I'm going to assume that the  x-axis is measured in elephants and the y-axis in mouses. In which case, I would have to say that I'm not sure how mouses and elephants have to do with supercooling or cooling in any way.

Comment: Hahahaha! After reading that comment, I was smirking in my class; I am so sorry for not mentioning that, I thought I had it on the image, but since I didn't see the preview, that happened.

Comment: @weirdpanda: Laugh all you want but without an accurate description of the experiment no one here will be able to throw some light on your bump. Personally I do have an idea what it *might* be but I won't make a fool of myself by speculating on such little information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is (probably) caused by supercooling.

You might be interested to have a look at [this Google search to see lots of similar examples](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=cooling%20curve%20supercooling&tbm=isch). From this search I found [this article that gives a nice description](http://www.chemprofessor.com/phase.htm) - see the section titled *Solidification*. The figure they show is:

[image: Supercooling]

which is obviously similar to your cooling curve.

What happens is that the liquid cools to below the freezing temperature. The liquid to solid transition releases heat - when a mass $m$ of the liquid freezes the heat released is $Lm$ where $L$ is the [latent heat of fusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enthalpy_of_fusion). When solidification of the supercooled liquid starts this released heat pushes the temperature up again. Hence the dip and rise in the cooling curve.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was probably what I was looking for! :)